# c# multithreading method name expected

Tags: c#, multithreading, methods

I'm trying to create a loop which creates a thread for each program in a list, but i'm getting a "method name expected" error upon passing perimeters on the code below;

```
for (i = 0; i <= programs.Count; i++)
{
    checkProcess check = new checkProcess();
    // check.isRunning();

    string filename = programs[i].Filename;
    string filepath = programs[i].Filepath;

    mWorkerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(check.isRunning(filename, filepath)));

    mWorkerThread.Start();
}
```

I read a little on delegates but couldn't seem to get them to work in the context of my problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated as to what direction i should be heading.

Comment: To tell you the truth i'm not sure how..lemme take a quick look. Edit: got it!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The thread target ought to be something executable and not the result of your method.

```
mWorkerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(check.isRunning(filename, filepath)));
```

In your case above, you try to create a new instance of `ThreadStart` with the *return value* of `check.IsRunning(...)`. What you want is something like

```
mWorkerThread = new Thread( () => check.isRunning(filename, filepath) );
```

Comment: Works brilliantly : ) thank you. What does the => symbolise exactly?

Comment: It's an anonymous function definition. More info on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Answer (score 2):

In your statement `mWorkerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(check.isRunning(filename,   filepath)));` **check.isRunning** is the method name that called on the start of the thread.

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadMethod));
t.Start("My Parameter");

// method that will be called
    private void ThreadMethod(object parameter)
    {
        // parameter equals to "My Parameter"
    }
```

Another expect is the anonymous delegate method that make your method inline.. using lambda expression:

```
   Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(()=>ThreadMethod(parmaValue) ));
    t.Start("My Parameter");
```

Ref: 
[ThreadStart with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195896/c-sharp-threadstart-with-parameters)