# How Start Methods With Arguments Using Thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, methods, arguments

For Create And Start New Threads In C# We Act Like Below :

```
using System.Threading;

Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WorkThreadFunction));
thread.Start();

public void WorkThreadFunction()
{
  //Stuff Here
}
```

but what about methods with arguments.
for these methods the codes below have an error.

```
using System.Threading;

int a = 5;
int b = 6;
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WorkThreadFunction(a, b)));
thread.Start();


public void WorkThreadFunction(int a, int b)
{
  //Stuff Here
}
```

**ERROR :**

> Method name expected

i need to pass those parameters to that method!
what is the solution?

thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# ThreadStart with parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195896/c-sharp-threadstart-with-parameters)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a lambda expression for encapsulating the invocation of your method with parameters:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => WorkThreadFunction(a, b)));
```

Comment: `ParameterizedThreadStart`. Refer to the linked answer in Chris Gessler’s comment.