# How to put a method with one parameter into the Thread C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# ThreadStart with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195896/c-sharp-threadstart-with-parameters)

How to put a method with one parameter into the Thread C#.

Example:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(SoundInputThread.getSomething(hz));
                 thread.Start();
                 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                     Console.WriteLine();
                     Thread.Sleep(1000);
                 }


     public static void getSomething(int hz) {
            hz = 100;
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  If so, what are they?

Comment: A Thread-Object has to be created ether by paasing in a ThreadStart or a ParameterizedThreadStart object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use overloaded constuctor of Thread which takes [**ParameterizedThreadStart**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx) It will allow passing parameter to thread method. In the method you can csat object back to your type.

```
thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(getSomething));
thread.Start(2);

public static void getSomething(object obj) {
      int i = (int)obj;
}
```

Comment: then i suppose: int a = (int)obj; ?

Comment: Yes, I already updated that.

Comment: Ok so one last more... how to pass an int by the reference not value?

Comment: You can use type casting to object like (object) i

Comment: @Robert You don't, you pass a reference to an object that contains an integer, and then modify that object from another location.  In any case, that's really a separate question.

Answer (score 3):

You can capture the value as follows:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() => {
   getSomething(hz);
});
thread.Start();
```

Comment: The primary advantage of this over a parameterized thread start is that you don't need to cast (or box) the parameter, and also that you can have more than one parameter.