# How does one return a value from a thread with parameters?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Using the answer about the lambda operator from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195896/c-sharp-threadstart-with-parameters), I've got a thread that accepts parameters and works fine. However I'd like to be able to get stuff back from the thread. This is what the code looks like:

```
namespace Renamer
{
    class RenameThread
    {
        public Thread StartRename(bool commit, ICollection checkeditems, ArrayList rules)
        {
            var t = new Thread(() => doRename(commit, checkeditems, rules));
            t.Start();
            return t;

        }
        private void doRename(bool commit, ICollection checkeditems, ArrayList rules)
        {
            ArrayList filenames = new ArrayList();
            ArrayList newfilenames = new ArrayList();
            filenames.AddRange(checkeditems);
            //do stuff with filenames
            //I want to be able to return newfilenames (or perhaps some object that contains it)
        }
    }
}
```

It gets called from clicking on a button:

```
private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RenameThread rt = new RenameThread();
    Thread renameThread = rt.StartRename(false, clbFiles.CheckedItems, rules);
    renameThread.Join();
}
```

In Java I'd just implement `Runnable` so I could get direct access to the thread's members and fields if I needed them, but since I can't inherit from `Thread` I'm at a bit of a loss as to what I should do.

Comment: `Thread.Join` blocks until the thread is finished. You could just run your code synchronous...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use [Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx):

```
var renameTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Rename(...));
```

You can now wait for the task to finish, similar to your `Join`, by accessing `Result`:

```
var newFilenames = renameTask.Result;
```

Or you could do that asynchronous:

```
renameTask.ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine(t.Result));
```

My answer assumes that `Rename` is a method that returns a `string`.