# how to use string in multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, ip, ping, void

So I need to have my IP string to be used by 2 threads of my program. I don't know alot about classes and voids but at the time I have it kind of like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string IP = "127.0.0.1"
    }
```

and I want to use it in another thread:

```
    static void th1T()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var ping = new Ping();
            ping.Send(IP);
        }
    }
```

How can I get that to work? I know I am doing something wrong, but don't know what i shall use instead.

Comment: I'd use a parameter for the invoked method that accepts the IP string. See if that's possible for you.

Comment: How do you create the new thread? You can use this question as a reference for creating a new thread with parameters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195896/threadstart-with-parameters

Comment: i know how to create a new thread, thats not the question. i just didnt copy it to the question

Comment: Right, but isn't your issue that you don't know how to access the IP variable in the thread? That question shows you how. Additionally, you can look at Ian P or Darin Dimitrov's answers.

Comment: "I don't know alot about classes and voids" -- I don't mean to offend, but it sounds like you're trying to run before you can crawl. A basic understanding of language features such as classes and return types should be achieved before attempting more complicated subjects such as multithreading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first issue is that `IP` is scoped to the method `Main`. You'll need to declare `IP` somewhere `th1T` can get to if you truly want to share it.

```
static string IP = "127.0.0.1"

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // do some work and start th1T()
}

static void th1T()
{
    while (true)
    {
        var ping = new Ping();
        ping.Send(IP);
    }
}
```

Here you'll be able to reach `IP` even if `th1T` is running on a different thread. There are some other options as well though, like *injecting* the IP into `th1T` when the thread is started. To do that you'd have to change the signature of `th1T` to this:

```
static void th1T(object data)
```

and you'd have to change the code a little:

```
static void th1T(object data)
{
    while (true)
    {
        var ping = new Ping();
        ping.Send(data as string);
    }
}
```

You could then start that on another thread like this:

```
Thread newThread = new Thread(th1T);
newThread.Start(IP);
```

Threading is very much a subjective subject. If the value you're referencing from another thread is being *read only*, like in your example, and it's only set once by the controller (the class starting the work), then it's absolutely valid to share the variable between threads. Many however will argue to their death on this.

We can only speak in generalities in respect to this issue. For example, *in general* it's more appropriate to inject the value to avoid race conditions and dead locks. But again, that would really depend on what you're doing with the value. You can't *inject* the value if you're reading a flag from one thread that's set by another. In that case you have to safely *synchronize* the value.

There's no need to continue because as you see the rabbit hole only gets deeper.

Comment: I don't believe that would be a smart move; maybe just as a quick fix. It would very much depend on the program of course.

Comment: @OMer Obaid, when Ken commented, the solution in this answer was just to make IP a global variable.

Comment: @SeanCogan Yes, it was. So Omer the reason is that global variables should be avoidable by default in-order to reach a maintainable architecture and design (which is so **pleasuring** to me, btw). I did remove my downvote now because of 2nd solution, but I still think what I said should be noted in the answer aswell (that it's not advisable).

Comment: @Ken, clearly I understand your position, but I did address it for you. As I stated, we can only speak in generalities because there are absolutely scenarios where *injecting the value* is not a solution. There are times that you must keep the value *synchronized*, and honestly, there are times you don't need to.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Completely agree. you got my vote for your fantastic answer :).

Comment: but lets say im assigning the IP in the Main void. This is acutally what i wanted to do, i didnt know that it is that different :P.

Comment: @user3002135 Declare `static string IP;` outside Main, and inside Main assign `IP = "127.0.0.1";`.

Comment: @Ken hm for me it said in debug mode that `IP = NULL`

Comment: @Ken nevermind i just did something wrong there... now it works :)

Answer (score 1):

You should refactor your method that pings to accept a string as a parameter:

```
static void th1T(string IP)
{
    while (true)
    {
        var ping = new Ping();
        ping.Send(IP);
    }
}
```

And when you call the method, pass in your IP.

What you're wanting to do amounts to a global variable, which is generally not a good idea.

Another approach you could use is a static class to store the value:

```
public static class Values
{
    string IP { get; set; }
}
```

And in your method:

```
static void th1T()
{
    while (true)
    {
        var ping = new Ping();
        ping.Send(Values.IP);
    }
}
```

I want to add that there are several issues that could arise from this approach. It is probably not a best practice to do it this way.

Comment: at this one it says it needs reference at Values.IP

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown how you are starting the thread but in all cases you have the possibility to send the string as parameter to the thread. For example if you are manually spawning a new Thread you could pass it as parameter to the [`Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x4c42hc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string IP = "127.0.0.1"
    Thread t = new Thread(th1T);
    t.Start(IP);
} 

static void th1T(object value)
{
    // The value parameter will contain the IP here
    string ip = (string)value;
    while (true)
    {
        var ping = new Ping();
        ping.Send(ip);
    }
}
```

Notice how the `th1T` method now takes an object parameter that you could cast back to the value being passed. In this example we have passed a simple string value but you could pass arbitrary complex objects.

If you are using Tasks you also have the possibility to pass parameters:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string IP = "127.0.0.1"
    Task.Factory.StartNew(th1T, IP);
} 

static void th1T(object value)
{
    // The value parameter will contain the IP here
    string ip = (string)value;
    while (true)
    {
        var ping = new Ping();
        ping.Send(ip);
    }
}
```