# Multi Thread in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a c# **windows form app**. Right now it works fine alone in single thread.
Here is how I launch it in a click on button.

```
botThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(mainThread));
botThread.Start();
```

So one thread gets launched.

The user will specify the number of threads to run at a time in a text box as number.
So I want that many threads to get launched and each thread should get a line from a text file. so if the thread is first, it should get the first line of a text file.

If a user specified two threads, once the first instance of thread ends doing the job or it had any expection, i want the bot to move to the next instance and start a new thread with the 3rd line of text file.

I am not sure what to do. I tried using for loop but i couldn't keep track of the threads and couldn't launch new ones when one ends

edit :
Here is for loop code :

```
int j = int.Parse(settings_textbox_instances.Text);
            for (i = 0; i < j; i++)
            {
                botThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(mainThread));
                botThread.Start();

            }
```

edit 1 :

I have worked with the code and made this.

```
private void multiThreader(int instances)
        {

            for (i = 0; i < instances; i++)
            {
                botThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(mainThread));
                string text = this.users_List[this.i];


                botThread.Start();

                threadcount++;
                MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());

            } 
        }
```

so when ending the thread i can call the void in to create new instances. But can anyone say to me on how i can transfer the value of text from here to the thread ?

Comment: Yeah , then post the loop

Comment: added it to my first post please check it

Comment: So, according to your question, you want to sequentially multitask your app.

Comment: why doing multithread if all is synchronous ?

Comment: @ThaMe90 Yes, i want my app to multi task.

Comment: @Xaruth, i don't get you ?

Comment: Sequential multitasking is contextually impossible. If you want to multitask, you do tasks parallel to each other. Not sequentially (i.e. one after the other).

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to allow the user to manage the number of threads?

You can let the framework take care of the detail and use the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Here is a simple example of usage...

```
 static void Main()
{
    var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp\log.txt");
    Parallel.ForEach(lines,line => processLine(line));
}

private static void processLine(string line)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

As well as the TPL documentation linked above, i would highly recommend reading [Joe Albaharis excellent series on Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) to gain a richer understanding of the concepts.

Answer (score 1):

You could instead use Parallel.ForEach

```
        var l = new List<string>();
        using (var fs = new FileStream("", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    l.Add(line);
                }
            }
        }
        Parallel.ForEach(l, new ParallelOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10}, line => Console.WriteLine(line));
```

for clarity

```
        Parallel.ForEach(l, new ParallelOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10}, MyAction);

    private void MyAction(string s)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Where MaxDegreeOfParallelism would be the number provided by the textbox.

Comment: it is not a console. My main problem here is lauching the threads multiple times

Comment: the console.writeline is only there to have an action, you can specifiy your own action to be wathever processing needs done on the string... see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

you can use on your code this function to see when you start your another thread :

```
//return true if the thread is alive else false
botThread.IsAlive



int j = int.Parse(settings_textbox_instances.Text);
            for (i = 0; i < j; i++)
            {
                botThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(mainThread));
                botThread.Start();
                while (botThread.IsAlive)
                {}
                botThread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(mainThread));
                botThread2.Start();
            }
```

Comment: as the previous one process is alive he will not go to the next process. 
the while loop ensures that the process is still alive.

Comment: you can use a global variable and put the line of your text. and you start in the next line when you done your processing.

Comment: i have came up with a idea and updated my question. Can you help me to say how to transfer the text from my fucntion to thread.

Comment: sorry I dont know about the question second part

Comment: But that has been asked before, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195896/threadstart-with-parameters).