# Line Suppression State Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart'

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace assignment_1_q2
{
    class program
    {
        public static int SumNumbers(int s, int e, int p)
        {
            switch (p)
            {
                case 1:



                    int nnsum = 0;
                    for (int i = s; i <= e; i++)
                    {
                        nnsum = nnsum + i;

                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("sum of natural numbers = {0}", nnsum);
                    break;

                case 2:


                    int nnsum1 = 0;
                    for (int i = s - 1; i <= e; i = i + 2)
                    {
                        nnsum1 = nnsum1 + i;

                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("sum of natural even numbers = {0}", nnsum1);
                    break;

                case 3:



                    int nnsum2 = 0;
                    for (int i = s; i <= e; i = i + 2)
                    {
                        nnsum = nnsum2 + i;

                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("sum of natural odd numbers = {0}", nnsum2);
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("no priority matches");
                    break;

            }
            return 0;
        }
        static void main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread t1 = new Thread(SumNumbers(1, 10, 1));
            Thread t2 = new Thread(SumNumbers(1, 10, 2));
            Thread t3 = new Thread(SumNumbers(1, 10, 3));
            t1.Start();
            t2.Start();
            t3.Start();

        }
    }
}
```

I am getting this error by simply passing arguments to method "SumNumbers".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a lambda expression to pass parameters to your function

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(() => SumNumbers(1, 10, 2));
Thread t2 = new Thread(() => SumNumbers(1, 10, 2));
Thread t3 = new Thread(() => SumNumbers(1, 10, 3));
```

please take a look at this answer

[ThreadStart with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195896/threadstart-with-parameters)

Comment: Thankyou so much for helping me out...

Comment: Sir, can you please explain the use of delegate using my code?

Comment: The problem was the passing of parameters, the Thread constructor it takes the delegate ParameterizedThreadStart as a parameter that only allows passing a single parameter (object type) to the start method, it is a limitation but 
we can use a lambda expression to pass all parameters to a function, in this case the function "SumNumbers"
PS: I will update my answer. 

Please take a look at this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195896/threadstart-with-parameters